# Increase a variable value by 1 everytime another variable increases by 10

Tags: javascript

I want to increase a variable value by 1 every time the another variable increases by 10.

Example:
A page should have 10 rows, if exceeds 10, the page number will increase by 1.

```
var pagenumber = 1;//default
var rows = 10;//dynamic value
```

When rows is 20, the page number should be 2.
When rows is 21, the page number should be 3.
When rows is 15, the page number should be 2.
When rows is 35, the page number should be 4.

I hope my explanation is not confusing.
(the rows value is set by a function, so rows variable value is dynamic)

So how can i achieve this?

Comment: You should use modulo.

Comment: If your maintaining the row counts somewhere, maybe a variable, then use this value to check its multiple of 10 and increase page number variable. `if((tblRows%10)==0){ pageNum++;}`

Comment: pagenumber = (rows / 10) + ((rows % 10 > 0) ? 1 : 0)

Comment: Why is the page number 3 for 35 rows?

Comment: When rows is 35, the page number should be 4. right???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just compute the page number dynamically:

```
function get_page_number(elements, elementsPerPage) {
    return  Math.ceil(elements / elementsPerPage);
}

var pagenumber = get_page_number(rows, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// counters
var a = 0;
var b = 0;

// demo for the first 5 pages
while (b < 5) {
  a++;

  // increment b only when a is a multiple of 10
  if (a % 10 === 0) {
    b++;
  }

  console.log(a, b);
}
```

Output

```
1 0
2 0
3 0
4 0
5 0
6 0
7 0
8 0
9 0
10 1
11 1
12 1
13 1
14 1
15 1
16 1
17 1
18 1
19 1
20 2
21 2
22 2
23 2
24 2
25 2
26 2
27 2
28 2
29 2
30 3
31 3
32 3
33 3
34 3
35 3
36 3
37 3
38 3
39 3
40 4
41 4
42 4
43 4
44 4
45 4
46 4
47 4
48 4
49 4
50 5
```

Comment: That's what it sounded like he wanted but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a derived value with no other modifiers, consider using a function like so:

```
function pagenumber() {
    return Math.ceil(rows / 10); // rows needs to be global for this to work. You can also pass it as a parameter.
}
```

Comment: If `rows` is `10`, the result will be `0`.

Answer (score 0):

update the page number by this

pagenumber = Math.ceil(rows/10)

Thanks,

Dhiraj

Answer (score 0):

Why not just perform a test to divide the 'rows' by 10, then round up to the next integer value.

david

Answer (score 0):

Use a Setter

```
var pagenumber = 1;//default
var rows = 10;

function setRows (n) {
 rows = n;
 pagenumber = Math.ceil(n/10)
}

setRows(20);

console.log (pagenumber); //2
```

Or a getter/setter using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) on `window`

```
Object.defineProperty(window,"pagenumber",{
  get: function () {
   return Math.ceil((rows||0)/10)
  }
});


var rows = 19;
console.log(pagenumber); //1
rows = 22
console.log(pagenumber); //2
```

etc..

> When rows is 20, the page number should be 2.
>   When rows is 21, the page number should be 3.
>   When rows is 15, the page number should be 2.
>   When rows is 35, the page number should be 3. //4?

I'm a bit confused, do you want to [`ceil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) or [`floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) the value, divided by ten?

Answer (score 0):

```
pagenumber = Math.ceil((rows - 1)  / 10 + 1)
```